# Need advice on porch conversion to sunroom

Tags: windows, patio, porch, sunroom

First, a huge THANK YOU to the community for helping me through a major kitchen and living room renovation. Couldn’t have done without your advise and guidance.

I am now exploring the possibility of enclosing the front porch of our house with top to bottom windows, to create a sunroom in modern style. The porch is a thick slab and the roof is enclosed as well.

There are outlets in the ceiling as well as lights so the electrical part would be relatively easy.

I will likely be making this the insulated area with the possibly a split air heat pump to be used as needed. I will run electric for it from the side of my house where my shut off is located in the floor below (basement).

I am looking for advise on sourcing the materials. Windows, doors, floor finish. On the floor finish, I’ve been told that porcelain is the only thing that won’t Crack.

One other consideration is that this is the front of the house. How atypical is it for the front entrance be to sunroom? Anything I need to watch out for? Any good places to start as far as installing windows and the door, or should I sub this to the window company? How much should I expect to pay for windows and doors? Any advise at this exploratory stage is appreciated.

Finally, posting photos of the exterior, as well as the photos of the look we are going for.

Thanks so much!

[image]

[image]

The look I am going for

[image]

[image]

Comment: Utilizing the front porch as a sunroom is not unusual. You can use any weather-resistant materials to build the walls or cover them with cladding. I think you are better off hiring a contractor and purchasing the windows of your choice. Don't forget you might need a permit for the conversin.

Answer (score -1):

I’d check the structural adequacy of the porch. Many porches flex when you walk on them. However, your new floor surface cannot flex or it will crack.

Normal porches are designed to 1/240 deflection, interior rooms are designed to 1/360 and tile floors should be designed to 1/640 or higher.

Comment: The first two photos show the porch has a concrete floor, I don't think it is a raised slab.

Comment: Check with your local authority. I tried to do something similar and was surprised when I was told that I needed at least 2' of solid wall in each corner to resist lateral movement (makes sense in that a wall catches a lot more wind resistance than a pillar.